# Find users in AD group and add them into another group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have Kerio Connect server and it doesn't allow group inheritance. So I need to create one group for mail and another group for AD with similar users.

I wrote:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity Sales.Department |select SamAccountName |ForEach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity sales.mail -Members $_.SamAccountName}
```

And I need to make it for all groups with expression *.Department and mail groups with *.mail

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the group members of sales.department using `Get-ADGroup` and then add the group members to sales.mail using `Add-ADGroupMember`

```
$MemberList = (Get-ADGroup -Identity "sales.department" -Properties member).member
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "sales.mail" -Members $MemberList
```

Comment: it doesn't work because ADd-AdGoupMember needs arguments for "Member" parameter

Answer (score 0):

For that pupose you better use the `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` cmdlet instead of the `Add-ADGroupMember`: For me is working fine:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity Source-Group-Name |select SamAccountName |ForEach-Object {Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.SamAccountName -MemberOf Target-Group-Name}
```